# Getting better at proving continuity

Tags: real-analysis

How can I get better at distinguishing between continuity and uniform continuity?

If I were given an exam question asking me to prove if the function is uniformly continuous or continuous then I won't be able to answer it correctly. If it were asked explicitly, then I might not have as much difficulty, for example, prove $x^2$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. But if it asked, is the function $x^2$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then I might have just said yes and proved continuity instead even though it isn't uniformly continuous.

For continuity I know I must prove in the following matter: $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \forall x \in X, \exists \delta > 0 : |x - y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon.$$

For uniform continuity:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in X : |x - y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$$

But I still don't understand how to distinguish a function from being uniformly continuous or continuous if it doesn't tell me explicitly.

Comment: I think you got the interval mixed up: shouldn't it be $[0, \infty)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following properties might help you build some intuitions.

(1) Any continuous function defined on a closed and bounded interval $[a, b]$ must be uniformly continuous.

(2) If $f$ is a continuous function on $(a, b)$. then $f$ is uniformly continuous if and only if $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on $[a, b]$.

(3) If $f$ has the properties that $|f'|$ is bounded, then it is uniformly continuous. (on any interval)

(4) More generally, if $f$ satisfies $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C |x-y|^\alpha$ for all $x, y$, for some $\alpha, C>0$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

(5) Let $ f$ be defined and continuous on $(a, b)$. If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, c]$ and $[c, b)$ respectively, then it is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$.

Comment: And it would also help to have some counterexamples in hand. For instance, you could ask yourself, is the converse of (3) or (4) true?